# Looking for Mathematics Subject Classification

Tags: mathematics, paper-submission

I'm writing a math paper for submission to some journal or other and section 2.1.10 of https://www.ams.org/publications/authors/AMS-StyleGuide-online.pdf says I need a Subject Classification number in the top material of my paper.

The paper is about an original formula I developed for generating Pythagorean triples and then goes on to show how to find such triples "on demand" given criteria such as side length, perimeter, area/perimeter ratio, area, product, and side differences. Indeed, the title is "On Finding Pythagorean Triples".
I have looked here https://zbmath.org/classification/ and my best guess is that the number I'm looking for would begin with 11 (number theory) but that's as far as I can figure out. I don't even know the proper tag(s) for this question. Can anyone help me in my search?

Comment: What classification numbers do similar/related papers have?

Comment: From a quick search for "Pythagorean triples" on MathSciNet, 11D09 looks like a good bet: "Number theory : Diophantine equations : Quadratic and bilinear equations."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*(originally this was a couple of comments, but perhaps it should be an answer)*

Section *11: Number Theory* is on pp. 4-6 of [this current *Mathematics Subject Classification* (MSC) document](https://mathscinet.ams.org/msc/pdfs/classifications2010.pdf). Besides just looking for what seems to be appropriate there (often, however, this requires a much broader knowledge than the specific topic you're looking for), you can look for similar papers and see how they're classified. For example, you can try a [google scholar search for "Pythagorean triples"](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=%22pythagorean+triples%22), pick a possibly similar paper such as [*Height and excess of Pythagorean triples*](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/0025570X.2005.11953298?journalCode=umma20), and if you don't have access to it and you don't see any MSC's for it, you can look it up at [MR Lookup](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mrlookup) (freely available), click on the MR number to get [MR2126355](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=2126355), at which point you can see "11D09 (20M99)" (11D09 is the primary classification, 20M99 is a secondary classification). Repeat with other papers you find. Thus, in the case of [*Clifford algebras and Euclid’s parametrization of Pythagorean triples*](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00006-006-0019-2) I get [11D09 (11E25 15A66 20H20)](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=2303057). It appears (but do some more checks of this nature) that Nate Eldredge (in a comment) was correct -- 11D09 seems an appropriate classification, probably the primary classification.

Comment: Rather than the 2010 version, use the newly released [2020](https://mathscinet.ams.org/msnhtml/msc2020.pdf) version. (It makes no difference for this specific paper.)

Comment: @Andrés E. Caicedo: Thanks! FYI, I read somewhere (not at the link I gave) that the 2020 version was not yet ready, so I didn't even try to specifically search for it.

Comment: My past decade of research has allowed me to answer questions about diophantine-equations on Mathematics Stack Exchange (MSE) but my paper has little to do with them. None of the articles suggested resemble my paper about a new formula that "has it's advantages" over Euclid. I have searched hundreds of pages, spent hundreds on books and even asked MSE for help in finding prior art [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3369742/looking-for-references-to-pythagorean-triple-subsets). Your suggestion of $11D09$ appears to be correct even though I solve cubics and quintics. Thanks. :–)